# Only one product displayed in Woocommerce admin products list dashboard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

Has anybody had this problem before, in Woocommerce under all products I see just one product, if I delete it, I can see the next product, is a fresh installation of the plugin.

I will add this screenshot to show you what I mean.

[image: screenshot]

I can't find a solution for this, if I search for this problem nothing similar appears.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: First check on **"Screen options"** tab *(on the right top)* to see how many **"Number of items per page"** are set. This can be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I figured it out! Do you have the Admin Columns plugin?
Go to settings, admin columns pro, chose the page type "products" and then click "reset columns" :)

Answer (score -1):

Please update you mysql version on server. If you check the woocommerce status under woocemmerce tab in admin panel. There it will be high lig

Comment: Question is already 5 months old. Based on what information have you deducted that the MySQL version is the issue? And even if we do not know the version he is using at the moment to decide to what version to upgrade. And perhaps he cannot as the hoster won't allow him. Not even certain the user is using MySQL in the first place. He did not give that information, now has he?